# How to modify existing ios ABRecord address

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to edit existing iOS contact. Contacts can have any number of addresses and I want to edit one of those. I am able to add new address to the contact but can not edit it. Have also tried ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex but is not helping. Here is my code snippet

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef addrBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef existingContact = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addrBook, contact.deviceRecordId);

ABRecordSetValue(existingContact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)(contact.firstName) , &error);
ABRecordSetValue(existingContact, kABPersonLastNameProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(contact.lastName) , &error);

// Get Current Addresses
ABMultiValueRef addresses = ABRecordCopyValue(existingContact, kABPersonAddressProperty);
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(addresses);

// Append all Street line to one \n delimited string.
NSMutableString *streets = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
if (contact.address.street1 != nil) {
    [streets appendString:contact.address.street1];
}
if (contact.address.street2 != nil) {
    [streets appendFormat:@"\n%@",contact.address.street2];
}
if (contact.address.street3 != nil) {
    [streets appendFormat:@"\n%@",[contact.address.street3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:SPAAdditionalStreetSeparator withString:@"\n"]];
}

// Single Address
NSMutableDictionary *addr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


// Insert single address into the multi address with the specified label
CFTypeRef ctr = CFBridgingRetain(addr);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, ctr, (CFStringRef)@"work", NULL);
//ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex(multiAddress, ctr, index);

// Add the MultiAddress value into the person object
ABRecordSetValue(existingContact, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, &error);

ABAddressBookSave(addrBook, &error);
```

Comment: Just realized ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex would do just what I want. There was a bug in my code earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex would do just what I want. There was a bug in my code earlier.